# Google GMail Service ListReqquest returning no results when Q is set

Tags: vb.net, gmail-api

In the following code, ListRespones includes the first 100 emails from the Emails Sent folder when I bypass the ListRequest.Q.  However, when Iset the Q based on destination and time, the ListResponse is nothing.

```
steLabelID = SENT, GOOGLE_API_EMAIL = the email address ie noreply@mycompany.com blnClean and blnUnreadOnly are always false.  

ListRequest.Q = to:employee@company.com before:02/06/2024 11:47:33 AM after:02/06/2024 11:33:33 AM

ListResponse does not throw an error but includes no messages.  ListResponse is Nothing.

Any suggestions?

`Try
      GService = GetService()

      LabelID = GetLabelId(strLabelId)
      ListRequest = GService.Users.Messages.List(GOOGLE_API_EMAIL)
      If LabelID <> "" Then
        ListRequest.LabelIds = LabelID
      End If
      ListRequest.IncludeSpamTrash = False
      If blnUnreadOnly Then
        ListRequest.Q = "is:unread" 'ONLY FOR UNDREAD EMAIL'S...
      End If
      If blnClean Then
        str6MonthsAgo = Date.Now.AddMonths(-6).ToShortDateString
        ListRequest.Q = "before:" & str6MonthsAgo
        ListRequest.MaxResults = 500
      End If
      If strDestination <> "" Then
        ListRequest.Q = "to:" & strDestination
      End If
      If strDateBounce <> "" Then
        ListRequest.Q += "  before:" & CDate(strDateBounce).AddMinutes(2).ToString
        ListRequest.Q += "  after:" & CDate(strDateBounce).AddMinutes(-12).ToString
      End If
      ListResponse = ListRequest.Execute()`
```

- I have tried reformatting the dates.
- I have tried setting the Q by destination only.
- I have tried setting the Q by time only.
- I have tried NOT setting the ListRequest.LabelIds.
- I have found documenation that indicates my Q should be formatted correctly.
- I have tried including is:sent in the Q.
- I have manually checked the email's sent folder to make sure the email exists, and the date is within the before after.

I am expecting the ListResponse to include 1 Message.